# Gradle not building classname correctly

Tags: java, gradle, build

So I had a class named 'Helloworld' and have built the project with Gradle once after that I decided to rename the class into 'HelloWorld', and for some reason when I build it again and check inside the jar file I still have 'Helloworld.class' which is causing me problems as I need the exact class name.

I tried deleting the .gradle/caches but it didn't work.

I'm not really sure what files I should post to check if something is wrong so if someone comments I will edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd just recreate the project altogether. Otherwise, are you able to rename the .class file that's causing you problems?

Comment: I am able to rename it manually, but that's not really the solution I'm going for since I will probably have to build the project many times and it will get annoying to have to rename that class after every build.

Comment: Oh okay that makes more sense. I'm not sure, then - I tried to recreate the problem but didn't have any luck. Is there a reason you can't just create a new class with the name you want and then copy/paste your code?

Comment: So i deleted the entire class built the project without it then created the class again built it and it worked correctly this time. I dont know what that was but at least problem is now solved.